# Thread safety around "web" CurrentSessionContext / ISessionFactory.GetCurrentSession

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, thread-safety

I've seen some code that puts a lock around the following code:

```
if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(sessionFactory))
{
     CurrentSessionContext.Bind(sessionFactory.OpenSession());
}

ISession session = sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
```

`sessionFactory` is a DI-injected singleton and the configuration uses a "web" (not "managed_web") context.

Am I correct in assuming that this code does not require synchronised access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct.

Since web context uses HttpContext.Items there's no shared state that you need to manage manually.